# Enter multiple words into form input and retrieve corresponding data from database

Tags: php, jquery, sql

My search SQL currently retrieves submitted text and up to 17 similar matches.

I also need the same form input to take in multiple words(separated by spaces) and retrieve their corresponding data by exact match and none similar.

this is what I have now -

```
$word=$_POST['word']; 
$word = explode(" ", $word);

$searchString = $whereClause = "";
foreach($words as $word){
$searchString .= " OR word_eng LIKE '%".$word."%'";
}

$whereClause = ($searchString != "") ? " WHERE ".preg_replace('/OR/', 
'', $searchString, 1) : $whereClause;

$sql = "SELECT word_eng FROM words ".$whereClause." LIMIT 17 ";

echo $sql;

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
    echo $row["word_eng"];
}
```

I am getting the following error -

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/foneti2/public_html/howjsay/201701/searchResult.php on line 10
```

and echo $sql is telling me

```
SELECT word_eng FROM words LIMIT 17
```

which is getting all the words from database which i don't want

**UPDATE**

So thanks to you guys I have got it working to my needs but I still have a small issue - when retrieving multiple words from the database they are not being retrieved in the same order that is put into the input box. Any suggestions?

```
$word=$_POST['word']; 
$word3 = $_POST['word']; 
$word = explode(";", $word);
$noOfWords = count($word);
$word2 = $word3;

if($noOfWords == 1){
$searchString = " word_eng LIKE '".$word3."%'";

}
else { 

$searchString = $whereClause = "";
foreach($word as $word){
$searchString .= " OR word_eng LIKE '".$word."'";

echo $word;
}

}

$whereClause = ($searchString != "") ? " WHERE ".preg_replace('/OR/', 
'', $searchString, 1) : $whereClause;

$sql = "SELECT word_eng FROM words ".$whereClause ." LIMIT 17 ";
```

thankyou

Comment: Check the SQL `IN` clause. You could also look into parametrized queries.

Comment: No. `IN` will not work in this scenario

Comment: Till now, you have asked 10 questions. And, your 10 questions doesn't have any marked answer. When you ask question, people spend their precious time to help you to come out of the trouble. reward them by marking appropriate answer as correct answer. And, what I observed is you don't have **courage** to reply/respond back to the person who is helping you. This type of behavior is not acceptable in anywhere of the world.

Comment: sorry Nana I was editing the post i didn't mean to come off as rude I do appreciate your help allot - also I haven't been familiar with marking correct answers I have usually been saying thankyou in the comment which now i know is in correct

Comment: Again the same thing. I given you `$words` variable. You wrote `$word` in foreach. How you expect that it will work? You don't know how to copy also. @sosro. And, after this, *I'm getting error* will come from the seeker. '

Comment: yea i changed that now .. because you gave two variables the same name... I'm not getting any errors now but for some reason it doesn't seem to be functioning correctly but thanks for the help

Comment: Why to use different variables unnecessary when one variable can be used for different purposes.

Comment: i donno man I'm pretty new to this

Comment: "*..i donno man I'm pretty new to this*" Asking Question Since 2016 And New To This Field? You used my answer in your system and marking other answer as correct answer will make me re-think to answer to other question.

Comment: Look.. I have asked 10 questions since 2016 , I am new to SQL. I marked your answer correct as well previously but it seems it didn't save i marked it again now . Hope you feel better soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you mean, you have a input, and want to retrieve data from this input. Which is composed of words separated by spaces.
Try something like this:

```
$sql="SELECT word_eng FROM words WHERE word_end LIKE '%" . $word . "%' AND word_end LIKE '%" . $word2 . "%' LIMIT 17";
```

To optimize it, you can do a foreach for your words, with in it, you "update" your $sql string, by adding one AND ***.

And after your foreach, just add your LIMIT 17

Comment: hi , how would I reference variable $word2? from the second word in the input field?

Comment: With an explode.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the question, *multiple words are separated by spaces*.

```
<?php

$words = "Hi All This Is Testing";

//The explode() function breaks a string into an array.
//Since, words are separated by spaces
$words = explode(" ", $words);

$searchString = $whereClause = "";
foreach($words as $word){
  $searchString .= " OR word_eng LIKE '%".$word."%'";
}

$whereClause = ($searchString != "") ? " WHERE ".preg_replace('/OR/', '', $searchString, 1) : $whereClause;

$sql = "SELECT word_eng FROM words ".$whereClause." LIMIT 17 ";

echo $sql;

?>
```

***Case-1:*** If `$searchString` is not empty.

**Output:** *SELECT word_eng FROM words WHERE word_eng LIKE '%Hi%' OR word_eng LIKE '%All%' OR word_eng LIKE '%This%' OR word_eng LIKE '%Is%' OR word_eng LIKE '%Testing%' LIMIT 17*

***Case-2:*** If `$searchString` is empty.

**Output:** *SELECT word_eng FROM words LIMIT 17*

**Explanation:**

Using [explode()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp), All words (separated by spaces) are now stored in array. Looping each word and appending with `$searchString`. Then, if `$searchString` is not empty, then, replacing first occurrence of OR from `$searchString` through [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Comment: Warning: explode() [function.explode]: Empty delimiter in /home/foneti2/public_html/howjsay/201701/searchResult.php on line 5

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/foneti2/public_html/howjsay/201701/searchResult.php on line 8
SELECT word_eng FROM words LIMIT 17

Comment: Words are separated by spaces or not @sosro? Because, First, I tested and then wrote answer.

Comment: yea they are, i am wanting to enter the words into one input field of a form and submit to retrieve

Comment: In this line. `$words = explode(" ", $words);` Give space between `" "`. Otherwise, that error will come. you have not given space between `" "` @sosro

Comment: Copy whole code and do. From here, we can't see what you are writing there. @sosro

Comment: oh wait - i accidentally took out the space from explode()="" , so that error is gone now and only for foreach() issue :D

Comment: it's not possible that it will not work. Paste your tried code in question. We can't see what *accidentally* you are writing there.Have some responsibility @sosro

Comment: Where you went? Respond back @sosro

Comment: My answer didn't helped you right? As, you have marked other answer @sosro

Comment: See correctly. You have copied wrongly @sosro. Please, for god sake, don't do this type of accidental errors. I'm not sitting in your system. You are sole repsonsible for typing code in your system. Atleast, type correct code.